# Shall we make it easier to find the links to comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks, permalink

If you are the author of a post, or you are @Mentioned, you are notified when there is a comment, and are given a link to it. However, if you just want a link to the comment, there is no way of getting that link (usually something like `http://some-site.stackexchange.com/questions/19901/title-of-the-question?noredirect=1#comment61900_19901`). So if I want to link to a comment that I made on a post, I have no way of knowing what the link shoul­­­­­­­­­­­­d be.

So should we make it easier to get a permalink to a comment?

Comment: Timestamp links are extremely common throughout the internet, so remember the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamp on a comment is a link to that comment.

So right click on the comment's time stamp, select "copy link location" (or slight potential variants depending on Browser/Operating System/your settings) and paste it wherever required.

I doubt anything *easier* than that would be implemented, such as the "share" option on Questions and Answers, as comments are not really deemed as terribly important.
Also, the method I mentioned is pretty simple for the (likely) few times we need it.